# No more xorg.conf file in ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: drivers, xorg, files, intel

I was looking to make modifications to my xorg.conf file because I'm experiencing flash video tearing in the browser (with the xorg nouveau drivers on my intel hd graphics for the Intel D525 Atom processor), but when I went to /etc/x11/ I cannot find any xorg.conf.d folder or xorg.conf file. Am I missing something? I'm running Ubuntu 14.10.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in /user/share/X11/

If there is no xorg.conf file there, feel free to create one. In some cases xorg.conf is not needed.